# Reading data from a BM

Tags: pointers, bitmap, casting, embedded, post-increment

```
#define bmpSIGNATURE  0X4D42 

unsigned short Get16U(unsigned int *x)
{
    unsigned short temp ;
    temp = *x & (0xFFFF);
    return temp;
}

unsigned int *bAddress,fdr;

void main()
{      
    disp_str("FILE OPEN",1,0);
    disp_rw_clr(2);
    bAddress = FILE_Open((void *)pUSBDevInfo, Directory[dir_cnt].FileName, RDONLY); // Read the file from USB and return start address
    /* read bmp  header */
    pFileheader->Type = Get16U(bAddress);               // save the first two bytes of bmp file data 
    (char*)bAddress++;
    (char*)bAddress++;                                  // increment the address by 2 bytes to reach address of "Filesize" parameter 
    if(pFileheader->Type == bmpSIGNATURE)               // read further bytes of the FILE header and INFO header only if the file is a bitmap 
    { 
        pFileheader->FileSize = Get32U(bAddress);       // save the filesize
        bAddress = bAddress + 2;                        // increment the address by 8 bytes to reach address of "offset" parameter
        pFileheader->PxOffset = Get32U(bAddress);       // save the offset
        bAddress++;                                     // increment the address by 4 bytes to reach address of "info header size" parameter
    }
}
```

OKay here is a part of a code I have written to read a bmp file header after opening it from a usb drive. In the read bmp part I want to increment the unsigned integer pointer `bAddress` by one byte i.e as a char pointer `((char*)bAddress++)`, so that I will reach the data I want to read. Now (if I increment the pointer as `(bAdress++)`) I will reach the wrong data as address will be incremented by 4 bytes). I am confused if I have done that right or wrong by using `(char*)bAddress++;`

Comment: Why have you declared `unsigned int bAddress` which is not a pointer? Is this your code or something that resembles it?

Comment: sorry.i forgot to write *bAddress

Comment: this is only a part of my code